# How to identify a separator and how to use it with a path Open Inventor

Tags: c++, 3d, openinventor

I have a few separators such as desk, lamp, and frame in my scene graph. When I add them to a separator called, "root," are they then made into nodes? Like if I wanted to use them with a path, is there an equivalent to path->containsNode for separators?

Also, is there a way to identify a separator? Let's say that I would like to place a lamp on a desk. I think the best way would be to check if the lamp collides with a specific separator like desk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [`SoSeparator`](http://doc.coin3d.org/Coin/classSoSeparator.html) inherits from `[SoNode][2]` via `SoGroup` in the C++ inheritance sense.  In other words, any `SoSeparator*` (i.e. your lamp, desk, ...) is a node.  Just use any `SoSeparator*` anywhere it calls for a `SoNode*` argument and you should be good.

Do you have [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and a copy of [The Inventor Mentor](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Membres/Francois.Faure/doc/inventorMentor/sgi_html/) on hand?